# Trouble in getting in customer data using block class

Tags: magento2.3, blocks, template, customer-session

I'm having trouble in getting the customer details using block class. I want to show the customer name after he/she logged in using block class. I can do it via object manager but not through block.

Below are my code:

**Block file:**

```
<?php 

namespace vendor\module\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class Testing extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;

    }
    public function getCustomerName(){
        $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
    }
}
```

**In template file:**

```
<?php echo $block->getCustomerName(); ?>
```

**In XML:**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
     <block class="vendor\module\Block\Testing" name="customer.session.data" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml" cacheable="false" />
 </referenceContainer>
```

When I try to load the customer name, its not working.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in your Block file

```
<?php 

namespace vendor\module\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class Testing extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function getCustomerName(){
        return $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
    }


    public function getCustomerId(){
        return $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    }
}
```

In template file you can direct access your Block file's function like this

```
<?php echo $block->getCustomerName(); ?>
<?php $customerId =  $block->getCustomerId(); ?>
<img src='<?php echo $this->helper("SK\ProfilePic\Helper\Data")->getProfilePicById($customerId); ?>' alt="Demo">
```

Because you have used this block class for this template in your XML file here

```
<block class="vendor\module\Block\Testing" name="customer.session.data" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml" cacheable="false" />
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks @Kishan. I'm getting the image now using block.

Comment: You're welcome @Siva

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it correctly. You just need to change

this:

```
public function getCustomerName(){
    $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
}
```

to:

```
public function getCustomerName(){
    return $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
}
```

You forgot `return`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried as you said but still its not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Answer updated, please check now

Comment: Its working thanks.

Comment: If I want to show the customer image using customer Id, How can I proceed?

Comment: I have added a function for getting customer ID: 
public function getCustomerId() {
     return $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    }
and now I have <img src='<?php echo $this->helper("SK\ProfilePic\Helper\Data")->getProfilePicById($customerData); ?>' alt="Demo">